# Go get problem when using testcontainer-go

Tags: go, testcontainers

I was trying out the sample of the page https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "testing"

    testcontainer "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go"
)

func TestNginxLatestReturn(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    req := testcontainer.ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "nginx",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"80/tcp"},
    }
...
}
```

but when I put the code in the file `main.go` under `<home>/go/src/my-sample` and call `go get`, I just get this error:

#

```
 github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go
../github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go/docker.go:116:32: cannot use inspect.NetworkSettings.NetworkSettingsBase.Ports (type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap) as type "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap in return argument
../github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go/docker.go:197:25: multiple-value uuid.NewV4() in single-value context
../github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go/docker.go:219:3: cannot use exposedPortSet (type map["github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".Port]struct {}) as type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet in field value
../github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go/docker.go:261:3: cannot use exposedPortMap (type map["github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".Port][]"github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortBinding) as type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap in field value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the problem as well, but I did manage to build and run the test with the following steps:

1. Create a `my_package` directory outside of the `$GOPATH` tree.
2. Create a `mypackage_test.go` file with the following content:

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "testing"

       testcontainer "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainer-go"
   )

   func testNginxLatestReturn(t *testing.T) {
       req := testcontainer.ContainerRequest{
           Image:        "nginx",
           ExposedPorts: []string{"80/tcp"},
       }
       t.Log(req)
   }
   ```
3. `go mod init mypackage`
4. `go test`